# XArray - Multidimensional Binning & Array Reduction on Sample Dataset of 4 x4 to 2 x 2

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to reduce an Xarray from 4 x 4 to 2 x 2 via both the dimensions. I haven't found any luck with the current Xarray Dataset.
These are the steps I followed. I want to bin or group based on latitude and longitude.

```
a = np.array(np.random.randint(1, 90+1,(4,4)),dtype=np.float64)

b = np.array(np.random.randint(1, 360+1,(4,4)),dtype=np.float64)

c = np.random.random_sample(16,)

c = c.reshape(4,4)

dsa = xr.Dataset()

dsa['CloudFraction'] = (('x', 'y'), c)

dsa.coords['latitude'] = (('x', 'y'), a)

dsa.coords['longitude'] = (('x', 'y'), b)

dsa
```

Dimensions:        (x: 4, y: 4)

Coordinates:

```
latitude       (x, y) float64 23.0 16.0 53.0 1.0 ... 82.0 65.0 45.0 88.0
longitude      (x, y) float64 219.0 13.0 276.0 69.0 ... 156.0 277.0 16.0
```

Dimensions without coordinates: x, y

Data variables:

```
CloudFraction  (x, y) float64 0.1599 0.05671 0.8624 ... 0.7757 0.7572
```

Comment: I've tried running the code you provided, but the line `dsa['CloudFraction'] = (('x', 'y'), c)` results in `ValueError: dimensions ('x', 'y') must have the same length as the number of data dimensions, ndim=1`. Are you sure this code produces the dataset you're working with?

Comment: Yes. Although I missed a line in the code. To reshape c. It should have been

**` c = c.reshape(4,4). `**

before dsa = xr.Dataset()

 and rest is the same. This should solve the above mentioned error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

delgadom.

We can realize the (moving) binning for your example by using `rolling` method.
A simple way to bin along x axis is

```
In [14]: dsa.rolling(x=2).mean().isel(x=slice(1, None, 2))
Out[14]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (x: 2, y: 4)
Coordinates:
    latitude       (x, y) float64 9.0 61.0 58.0 57.0 23.0 38.0 10.0 75.0
    longitude      (x, y) float64 198.0 177.0 303.0 71.0 163.0 213.0 55.0 102.0
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    CloudFraction  (x, y) float64 0.2882 0.7061 0.9226 ... 0.5084 0.2377 0.6352
```

This actually computes the moving average with the window size 2, and then subsamples with stride of 2.

Since `mean` operation is linear, you can do the same thing for y-axis sequentially.

The above operation wasting a computation resource a little, since we only use a half of the computed values.
In order to avoid this, we can use `construct` method instead,

```
In [18]: dsa.rolling(x=2).construct('tmp').isel(x=slice(1, None, 2)).mean('tmp')
...: 
Out[18]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (x: 2, y: 4)

Coordinates:
    latitude       (x, y) float64 9.0 61.0 58.0 57.0 23.0 38.0 10.0 75.0
    longitude      (x, y) float64 198.0 177.0 303.0 71.0 163.0 213.0 55.0 102.0
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    CloudFraction  (x, y) float64 0.2882 0.7061 0.9226 ... 0.5084 0.2377 0.6352
```

For the details of rolling method, see the official page
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#rolling-window-operations

Personally, I think it would be nice if xarray has `bin` method for this purpose.
If you don't mind contributing, let's discuss on the Github issue page.

Comment: Hello Keisuske FUJII, Thanks for providing your suggestion. I did go through the link providedl above.  I won't mind taking this issue on the Github page. However do let me know how should I go about doing that as I am a beginner on this topic. Your help on this matter will be greatly appreicated. Again thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I have added the issue to the GitHub page of Xarray. Please find the link below to this issue:
https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2525